# How to prevent Powershell from automatically changing temporarily back to default font when command is under execution

Tags: windows, powershell, fonts

I have installed on-my-posh and changed the font of my Powershell terminal to fit it. Which works mostly fine. But when I execute commands it changes back to default font before the execution finishes. Which makes the window looks like 'bouncing' when running simple commands like ls.

Digging into the internet still leave me clueless why this happens and how to prevent it. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This may be [a common problem](https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/issues) with **oh-my-posh**.  If you don't see your specific issue listed, then I suggest creating a [New issue] to inform the developer.  Sorry, but I'm unsure how many SO PoSh developers are actually using that theme engine for a 'proper' solution.  Good luck.